# Let There Be Light Story Identification

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, isaac-asimov

I am looking to identify a story that I read around 2001 (it is probably much older).  Someone showed me the story on pages printed from the internet, and it was attributed to Isaac Asimov (although I cannot state that is the true author).

The story is told in glimpses at different points of time in the future.  In each glimpse, humans are asking a more and more "intelligent" computer how to prevent the universe from collapsing into a singularity in the future, and the computer states it needs more computational power and resources to solve this problem.  At some point, man becomes one with the computer, and the computer exists in hyperspace (or subspace?).

In the final glimpse, it is the end of time and the universe is collapsing into a singularity.  At the instant the universe reaches the singularity, the computer figures out how to prevent it and says "Let there be light" and the universe begins to expand again.

Is anyone familiar with this story?

Comment: Many people asked Asimov the same question while he was alive: ["It is a curious fact that innumerable readers have asked me if I wrote this story. They seem never to remember the title of the story or (for sure) the author, except for the vague thought it might be me. But, of course, they never forget the story itself especially the ending. The idea seems to drown out everything -- and I'm satisfied that it should."](http://filer.case.edu/dts8/thelastq.htm)  There's a longer quote in a similar vein in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Question#History).

Comment: My first (and irrelevant) thought was the movie "The end of Dark Star" :)

Comment: @SethMMorton Sorry, but I have to ask. What exactly _did_ you search for on Google? You know it was attributed to Asimov, and you knew it contained "Let there be light"... If I search for only that, even without any quotes, "The Last Question" is the first link that comes up!

Comment: @AntalS-Z: this is repeated in an entry from the Isaac Asimov at http://www.asimovonline.com/asimov_FAQ.html#others7 which claims that “Asimov's own experience was that if someone couldn't remember the title of one of his stories (and especially if they weren't entirely sure if it was by him), then it was ‘The Last Question.’”

Comment: @MrLister You're right.  I looked under a list Asimov's works and couldn't see anything obvious, and searched for "let there be light story".  I don't know why I didn't just toss in "Asimov" in the "let there be light" search.  At the very least, it looks like others also had the same question, so I suppose *some* good came out of my search engine ineptitude.

Comment: Of amusing relevance is this [XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/1448/)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Science fiction story that ends with "Let there be light"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170208/science-fiction-story-that-ends-with-let-there-be-light)

Comment: @DavidW Agreed. That was the point.  Making a meta post.

Comment: @DavidW - No, we shouldn't dupe either of them off. ***The target question doesn't have an accepted answer.***

Answer (score 91, accepted):

["The Last Question"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41230), a short story by [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov), has its own [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Question). It was first published in [*Science Fiction Quarterly*, November 1956](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?60397+c), which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Science_Fiction_Quarterly_New_Series_v04n05_1956-11_slpn#page/n5/mode/2up). The text is also available at [Thrivenotes](http://www.thrivenotes.com/the-last-question/).

The universe is not collapsing into a singularity, it's the [heat death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe). Trillions of years after the end of the universe, the Cosmic AC finally figures out how to reverse entropy:

> The consciousness of AC encompassed all of what had been a Universe and brooded over what was now Chaos. Step by step, it must be done.
> And AC said, "LET THERE BE LIGHT!"
> And there was light-—
>
> THE BEGINNING

Comment: Thanks man.  I read it in high school between periods, so the details were a bit fuzzy.

Comment: This is in the recent VanderMeer anthology, _The Big Book of Science Fiction_.